# Talend - missing output

Tags: talend

I'm new to Talend, I just did some test.

I created a simple job that query SQL Server and writes on a xlsx file.

Query returns one record (tested on SSMS). And job seems to run fine:

[image]

It creates output files, names it correctly and, if specified, it also writes header in it.

But it does not write the record.

Mapping is one to one with the guessed schema. No filter or other operations on data.

What can I check?

== Edit - xlsx configuration ==
[image]

Comment: Can you share the tFileOutputExcel configuration?

Comment: @TRF  Added to question

Comment: We can see on the flow that 1 record comes out from the DB, goes into the tMap before to enter the XLS file. However, we cannot see what's inside the record. May "blank" values that you cannot see inside the Excel file.
I suggest you to add a tLogRow before and after the tMap to see the "real" record content.

Comment: @TRF You are right: blank values. This is odd, because if I preview the query (in tMSSqlRow_1 I click "component", then the ... button right to query and I run, it returns one row with correct values).

Comment: Try changing tMSSqlRow by tMSSqlInput

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we discover together, you need to replace your tMSSqlRow by a tMSSqlInput component in your job.

Regards,
TRF